# Unable to understand why channel size reduces after MaxPool2D operation in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement the Xception model using Tensorflow 2.0. For reference , I am using the architecture from the screenshot below.

[image: First Module]

I was trying to implement the first Xception module in the **Entry Flow** portion of the neural network and I got an error with regards to channel size mis-match. The code is as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras    


class Xception_entry_flow(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,filters_1,activation,size_1,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
            
        self.main_layer = [
            keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters = filters_1,kernel_size = size_1,activation = 'relu',padding='same'),
            keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters = filters_1,kernel_size = size_1,activation = 'relu',padding='same'),
            keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= 3,strides=2,padding='same')

        ]

        self.skip_layer = [

            keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = filters_1,kernel_size=1,strides=2,padding='same')

        ]

        self.activation = keras.activations.get(activation)
            
            
    def call(self,inputs):
        Z = inputs
        for layer in self.main_layer:
            Z_1 = layer(Z)
            
        print('Shape of Image after main layer')    
        print(Z_1.shape)
            
        for layer in self.skip_layer:
            Z_2 = layer(Z)
        print('Shape after skip layer')    
        print(Z_2.shape)


        return self.activation(Z_1+Z_2)

model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,strides = 2,activation='relu',input_shape =[229,229,3]))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='relu'))
model.add(Xception_entry_flow(filters_1=128,size_1=3,activation ='relu'))
```

After running the above code, I get the following error:

```
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 128 for 'xception_entry_flow_12/add' (op: 'AddV2') with input shapes: [?,56,56,64], [?,56,56,128].
```

The outputs of the main layer and the skip layer (Conv (1X1) and stride = 2X2) are as follows

```
Shape of Image after main layer
(None, 56, 56, 64)
Shape after skip layer
(None, 56, 56, 128)
```

I am not able to understand why the channel size reduces after applying `keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= 3,strides=2,padding='same')` operation in the main layer.

My assumption is  that the `keras.layers.SeparableConv2D` operation accepts the filter size argument based on what the output channel size should be. Is my assumption about this function wrong?

The Tensorflow version I am using is as follows :

**Tensorflow Version : 2.0.0**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i thinks there is some error with what the layer is taking as argument, i would try to write the network with the Funtional API, a lot easier to write and read

Comment: you should try to plot your network to see whats the problem like this ```plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=False)```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug (i think), should be,

```
Z_1 = inputs
for layer in self.main_layer:
    # You currently got layer(Z)
    Z_1 = layer(Z_1)
```

Right now, you have `Z` which is a `(None, 112, 112, 64)` sized tensor (from last `Conv2D` layer in the `model`). You are actually applying `MaxPool2D` on that instead of the output of the `SeparableConv2D` layer of `self.main_layers`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I understood my mistake. The `call` function is the place where the change needs to be made as the Input is not changing in my code. So I modified it this way

```
def call(self,inputs):
        Z_1 = inputs
        for layer in self.main_layer:
            Z_1 = layer(Z_1)
            
        
        Z_2 = inputs
        for layer in self.skip_layer:
            Z_2 = layer(Z_2)
        


        return self.activation(Z_1+Z_2)
```